# Jenkins Xvfb libcrypto issue

Tags: selenium, jenkins, xvfb

I have a Jenkins Job(for Selenium headless testing). I have installed Xvfb plugin in Jenkins. But when I run the job it gives following error

```
/var/jenkins_home/Xvfb: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Not sure, though the libcrypto.so.10 is also available in PATH variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're getting is indicating that `Xvfb` can't find the shared object for libcrypto. This happens when the dynamic linker can't locate a dependency of an executable. Generally you can determine which libraries can't be found by using the [`ldd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) command as your Jenkins user, for example:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/Xvfb
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdc6def000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f6bcb054000)
libcrypto.so.10 => not found
```

The dynamic linker in Linux doesn't generally use the `PATH` variable to determine where to load libraries from. It usually looks in: the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, the contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf`, then `/lib`, and `/usr/lib`. More information [in this Unix Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367682/309249) or the [man page for ld.so](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

Where exactly it looks depends on the distribution you're using and how you've got it configured. You've got a few options for helping Jenkins find your library:

- Add the path for `libcrypto.so.10` to the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - This should work, but depending on what you're building this may mess up other things. Some (mostly C/C++) build scripts require this to be unset. This does have the advantage of only affecting your Jenkins user and not requiring additional privileges to set up.
- Add the path for `libcrypto.so.10` to the list of paths in the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or on some distributions into its own file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. This should work without the nasty side effects of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but requires root privileges and would affect any user on the computer.
- Copy (or symlink) `libcrypto.so.10` to `/usr/lib`. This is a brute force tactic and is probably a bad idea since it might mess with your distribution's packaging system but it should work if nothing else does.

Comment: I tried 2 option. Added the following configs in ld.so.conf
/var/jenkins_home/lib64/
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
Still geeting the same error.

Comment: Have you rebooted since changing your `/etc/ld.so.conf` file? If not try running `sudo ldconfig -v`. This should reload your configuration file and clear anything that might be cached.

Comment: thanks a lot. This really gave me an insight and fixed my issue.

Comment: Also found this refernece. Good to check for understanding. Good Article. 
https://codeyarns.com/2017/11/02/how-shared-library-locations-are-found-at-runtime/